# Options for setting value of a global naming resources environment variable

Tags: tomcat, environment-variables, server.xml

I'm using an environment variable in the web.xml which has a value that uses a cdata section, something like this:

```
<env-entry> 
    <env-entry-name>myEntry</env-entry-name> 
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type> 
    <env-entry-value>
<![CDATA[
<a>
    <b/>
</a>
]]>
    </env-entry-value> 
</env-entry>
```

I can read this value in my servlet and treat the string as XML.

Now I want to set an override in the Tomcat server.xml but I can only set the value using an attribute i.e.

```
<Environment name="myEntry" value="baz" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```

Is there a workaround that would allow me to set the value using a cdata section?

Really what I need to do is provide some configuration for my web application which is in XML format. I want to be able to change this configuration at deployment time and i need to support multiple servers (Tomcat, WebSphere, ...). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat supports [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) style variable-substitution from system properties: JVM system properties (both inbuilt/pre-defined and those defined with -D switch), and those defined in `catalina.properties`.  From [Tomcat 7.0 Configuration Overview](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/index.html):

> Apache Ant-style variable substitution is supported; a system property with the name propname may be used in a configuration file using the syntax ${propname}. All system properties are available including those set using the -D syntax, those automatically made available by the JVM and those configured in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.

So you can add

```
myValue=bar<with markup>baz
```

then:

```
<Environment name="myEntry" value="${myValue}" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```